# Arabic, Unicode and files in python

Tags: python, file, unicode

I am trying to grab some text written in Arabic from Youtube, writting it into a file and reading it again.

The source file to grab the text has:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#encoding: utf-8
```

in the beginning of the file.

Writing the text are done like this:

```
f.write(comment + '\n' )
```

The file contents is readable Arabic, so I assume the previous steps were correct.

But the problem appears when trying to read the contents from the file (and writing them for example into another file) like this:

```
in = open('data_Pass1/EG', 'rb')
out.write(in.read())
```

Which results in output file like this:

```
\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd9\x87
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Please specify whether you are using Python 2 or 3. They handle unicode strings differently.

Comment: And please specify type of a varaible `comment`.

Comment: `comment` is a string

Comment: Can be tricky sometimes, depending on your goal. I suggest you check out http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data.

Answer (score 11):

In python 3.x

```
in = open('data_Pass1/EG', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
out = open('_file_name_', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

In python 2.x.

```
import codecs
in = codecs.open('data_Pass1/EG', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
out = codecs.open('_file_name_', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the input file in binary ('rb') mode. Open the file to read as text ('r'). I tend to use Python 3 so the source files are UTF-8 by default, so I don't know what effect setting the encoding for .py files inside the files has on text I/O, but if necessary you may also want to use `encoding='utf8'` inside the calls to `open()` for all your file I/O, unless that doesn't work in 2.7 in which case I'm not sure what the best way to handle that in Python 2.7 would be...

---

As Lee Daniel Crocker suggests, you'd probably be better off just opening both input and output files in binary mode ('rb' for the input file, 'wb' for the output) if you're passing the input directly to the output without doing any textual manipulation of it. (Though going by Andy's comment, in Python 2 it's better to open text files in binary mode and do explicit encoding/decoding anyway.)

Comment: Most people will recommend nearly always using the 'rb' open mode (even when dealing with `str` types) in Python 2.

Comment: Nothing wrong with opening a file in binary mode. Bytes are bytes. It's more likely that `out` is *not* in binary mode that is the problem.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker True enough, and opening all the files in binary certainly would avoid any encoding issues...